# Unable to find python module installed by pip

Tags: python, pip

I have installed pip and pip3 by apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip`

And with pip I installed a python module and the dependencies without sudo:

`pip install kicost`

The libraries are listed by `pip list` command, but I can not find it with `python3 kicost` or `kicost`.

I tried other tips like putting `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` in the `$PATH` variable but that did not work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Installed by "pip3 install kicost", I typed wrong in the las message.

Comment: I know you said you didn't use sudo but check `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` (replacing 3.5 with your version of python as needed). You can also always turn to unix utilities like `find`.

Comment: This '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages' folder is empty. The modules are all in '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages'. The 'pip' and 'pip3' commands work fine.

Comment: I put this folder in $PATH and $PYTHONPATH, and nothing happens.
If I try `kicost`in this machine result `kicost: command not found`, in other machines with the same Ubuntu and packages works fine.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code use:

```
python3 -m pip install six
```

here python3 is your python version